# How to forge a signature in a custom PMAC implementation

Tags: mac, forgery

From a crypto challenge i have the following PMAC variant where the task is to forge a signature to fulfil a specific condition:

**Preparation:**
in the finite Field GF(2^128) with the polynomial x^128 + x^7 + x^2 + x + 1 as modulus we generate the PMAC-L constants like that:

**L(0)=AES(0)** -> standard AES-128 with a random fixed key K and the all 0 plaintext as input

**L(i) = L(i-1) * 2**  -> for i=1..257 the actual L is just the L before multiplied by 2 (decimal)

**The MAC:**

- we have a fixed block of 4096 bytes, which is filled with all 0
- we can copy an arbitrary text/bytes of up to 4095 bytes into that block for testing
- the block is then split into 256 * 16 byte messages and processed like

  **S = 0**

  **for i from 1..257 do S = S + AES(L[i] + M[i-1])**  (**+** means here addition in GF(2), **xor** otherwise)

  final step: **H = AES(S)**

  H is the 128 bit MAC then
- we can do 511 queries to an oracle with that setup
- no message padding is performed, just always processing all 256 16-byte  message blocks
- the oracle gives us only the 16 byte MAC as result of those operations

**The challenge:**

we have to to fill that 4096 bytes bufffer in such a way that the resulting hash is the same as AES(0). Some fixed 27 chars text is copied into the start of the buffer before, the remaining space is at our disposal.

I cannot see any angle of attack for a forgery, cause the only access for results is the result after that last AES step H = AES(S). And the only input available are the message blocks.

i think its ok to assume we aim at

AES(0) === AES(S) which would result in the condition
S === 0 ?

if there would be any way to know the results of single hashes like
AES(L[i] + M[i-1]), one could construct a basis of a vector space, and
maybe construct an arbitrary value which cancels out the result to 0 in the end - but this information is not available

I would be very glad about ANY pointer in ANY direction - thanks

PS: please dont be harsh with me when i used some mathematical terms not in the correct way

Comment: In the **L(i) = L(i-1) * 2** step, is the multiplication in $GF(2^{128})$ or integer multiplication modulo $2^{128}$?  Normally, it'd be the former, however your phraseology makes that unclear...

Comment: its unclear yes - its a left shift by 1 bit - no clue how to express it exactly

Comment: its like page 13 Figure 5 - without the additional steps in the end, the field description is on page 2 "preliminaries" https://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/offsets.pdf

Comment: If it is, in fact, integer multiplication modulo $2^{128}$, it's solvable.  Hint: first step is to recover most of the bits of $L(0)$ via a series of queries.

Comment: thank you for answering - i see no access to L(0) related to the last AES step AES(S)

Comment: Why don't you start with the hint: if we know the lower k-1 bits of $L(0)$, how could we perform two queries to test bit k (again, assuming that the multiplication is modulo $2^{128}$) that is, how can we generate two messages that have the same MAC if bit k is 0, but different MACs if bit k is 1?

Comment: @poncho actually, the OP was wrong, it isn't exactly multiplication modulo 2^128 but a left shift of one using the vpslld instruction (states are stored in xmm registers), which, according to the manual, performs individuals leftshifts on the four doublewords. Thus, if the most significant bit of a doubleword is 1, it won't be carried on the least significant bit of the next doubleword. Does your hint still hold ?

Comment: @Katoptriss: if it's multiplication by 2 in $GF(2^{128})$, then no, my hint does not apply...